# SQL Server Express, Windows 7, Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, windows-7-x64

As a .NET Desktop developer, I have a lot of experience working with various databases that are already up and running; but I'm not a DBA. I'm currently working at a company where I am ther *only* software guy here to build them software from scratch -- their previous enterprise-level solution was an Access database with macros and a couple forms built it. So, I basically have no one else to go to.

With that preface, how the heck do I get a database -- ANY DATABASE!!! -- added to my VS solution? I've been beating my head against this for almost 6 hours and have made zero headway. At this point, I'm ready to say, "Screw MS databases!" and start looking at MySQL or PostgreSQL or something.

The desktop application I'm developing has to work whether there is an internet connection or not, so I need a local database that installs with ClickOnce. From what I've found so far:

- SQL Server [Express] 2016+ requires Windows 8 or later (a non-starter since 95% our customers are still running Windows 7)
- SQL Server Compact is being deprecated and won't work past VS2013
- I think LocalDB is what replaces Compact in 2016+ (?)

Okay, so I started with this tutorial:https: //learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer However, trying to add a "Service-based Database" just gives me this error once: "The 'DBProviderFactories' section can only appear once per config file." I try again and get this error repeatedly: "Unable to find DbProviderFactory for type System.Data.SqlClientConnection" I've Googled both errors and all the answers that I've been able to find pertain to VS2010 or earlier and their solutions are either not applicable or don't work.

Next, I tried this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983322.aspx I've tried adding new data connections through the "Server Explorer" panel. I don't see "[*] Compact" as an option. When I try "Microsoft SQL Server Database File", I just get the error: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed."

I've even tried adding data sources through the "Data Sources" panel; that doesn't work either.

I've installed the "Data storage and development" addon from the Visual Studio Installer, several versions of SQL Server 2014, SQL Server Compact 4.0, and maybe a few other executables from Microsoft's website.

Nothing works.

Help...

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found it!

Evidently, there are "machine.config" files on your computer. Search for them all, and make sure that there is only a single tag for "DbProviderFactories". I can add a database object now. Hopefully, this puts me in business...

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7b4f353b-77fd-427c-976b-5968abc88c13/visual-studio-2010-unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-for-sql?forum=vseditor

Answer (score 0):

If what you are saying is that you are writing a browser based application - then one would migrate the tables to SQL Server (Express) or even MySQL - it really doesn't matter.  Then write a new web app.  The existing Access app would serve as a model for seeing features & screen layout but is otherwise not portable.

On the other hand, if you are re-writing a Windows application; then the decision is whether the payload requires a server solution or if one can stay at the PC level.  If the payload is suitable for PC then a re-write using either Visual Studio or Access again.

Access is a front end db - the tables in the back end whether they be stored in SQL Server or an Access file are entirely passive.  All the processing is done by the user's PC.  If the payload allows that then this is the lowest cost re-write option.

If you've outgrown a PC level payload - then one must develop a back end database feature set with a more passive front end.